# How to open DLUX UI in OpenDaylight controller in google cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, mininet, opendaylight

I am working in mininet + OpenDayLight in Google cloud. I can able to set-up mininet + OpenDayLight successfully in Google cloud and messages are flowing properly. Also installed the DLUX UI and YANG UI.

Now I would like to access DLUX UI and YANG UI in my local machine web-browser but I couldn't.

So could anyone please guide me to SSH the google cloud machine. So that I can access the URL locally or is there any other way possible to access the URL?

Note: I am a mac user.

Comment: Can you confirm that you installed the following: `feature:install odl-dlux-core odl-dluxapps-applications odl-dluxapps-yangutils` ?

Comment: @TamaYoshi thanks for your reply. Yep i have installed the feature what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with SSH you will need ssh tunnel between your machine and the ODL machine. This tunnel will redirect `127.0.0.1:8181` of your machine to the `ODL GUI 127.0.0.1:8181`.

To do so :

```sh
ssh -f -N -L 8181:127.0.0.1:8181 username@google.example.com
```

You can create a ssh config file, all the information is in this tutorial:
[nerderati - Simplify your life with and SSH config file](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)